# How to recognize End Of File in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to recognize the `End Of File` or end of class in eclipse using [eclipse API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Fpackage-summary.html).

For example to recognize beginning/ending of `ForLoop`s i do this:

```
public void Visit(ForStatement node){}
public void endVisit(ForStatement node){}
```

I tried several classes, like:

- [AnonymousClassDeclaration](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FAnonymousClassDeclaration.html)
- [BodyDeclaration](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FBodyDeclaration.html)

but none of them caught neither the beginning nor the ending of the class/file.

So what's the appropriate class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CompilationUnit is the AST representation of a java file and TypeDeclaration represents types i.e. classes/interfaces